Resources to master summation symbol
I noticed that I have some difficulties to use the summation tools( change of index, double or multiples summation...). Do you have some resources or book to master this topic. I am using concrete mathematics by Knuth

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Better than another source is it if you come here with a formula you do not understand.

There are some classic problems. Find a closed form expression for the Fibonacci sequence. That requires mostly re indexing.  There are various formulas for adding the  $pth$ power of the first several integers. You can prove the coefficient of the highest term is 1/(p+1) using double summation. 'Work those out until you have them pat and you should be good to go.

I think the best way to become comfortable with the summation symbol is to write out several terms with an ellipsis, so, for example
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n ix^i &= 1x^1 + 2x^2 + \cdots + nx^n\\
&= x(1 + 2x + \cdots + nx^{n-1})\\
&=x\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+1)x^i .
\end{align}
$$
That will serve you better in the long run than reading rules in some reference.

+1 .... instead of learning rules for this, write it out as shown.  After a while you can hopefully go directly to the last step, merely thinking of the intermediate steps without writing them.
